# beamer presentation with each figure on each slide using a foreach and pgfplots

Tags: beamer, pgfplotstable, tikz-datavisualization

Im doing a `beamer` presentation. With `pgfplots` I need to load a single column of a data file like this:

```
1   10  50  -50
2   11  51  -49
3   12  52  -48
4   13  53  -47
5   14  54  -46
6   15  55  -45
...
```

Each figure should be on each slide.

Im using this code, but I cant make it work correctly.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={svgnames,x11names,dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http;//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,calc,spy,shapes,petri,shapes.misc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,colormaps}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usetikzlibrary{
shapes,
shapes.geometric,
shapes.symbols,
shapes.arrows,
shapes.multipart,
shapes.callouts,
shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      clip=false,
      axis lines=center,
      height=5.5cm, width=8cm,
      x post scale=1.4
    ]
      \foreach \num in {1,2,3}
        \only<\num>{
          \addplot[
            DodgerBlue1,
            line width=0pt,
            fill=Blue,
            opacity=0.5
          ] table [
            col sep=tab,
            trim cells=true,
            x index=0, y index=\num
          ] {espectros_im_P_10_F_0_sigma_500.txt}\closedcycle ;
        }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Could you make your code so we can compile it? Presumably `\documentclass{beamer}` and then some packages are needed, then `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. If you could also clarify your question, it might be helpful. You say that each figure should be on each slide, but I think you want just one figure on each slide, is that right?

Comment: the \documentclass{beamer} or the enviroments \begin{document} are in the code. and you are right with the question...

Comment: They may be in *your* code, but they are not in the code you posted here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following what you want?

[image: plots]

The only things I changed were removing `col sep=tab` because the data came out spaced when pasted (so likely irrelevant to you) and moving the semi-colon. Everything else is just there because of missing definitions/packages in your sample code. For example, the colours were not necessarily defined, so I just switched to something standard.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
1 10 50 -50
2 11 51 -49
3 12 52 -48
4 13 53 -47
5 14 54 -46
6 15 55 -45
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      clip=false,
      axis lines=center,
      height=5.5cm,
      width=8cm,
      x post scale=1.4,
      ]
      \foreach \num in {1,2,3}
      \only<\num>{\addplot [blue, line width=0pt, fill=blue!20, opacity=0.5,]    table [trim cells=true, x index=0, y index=\num] {\jobname.dat}\closedcycle };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```